# Docker id not picking the file

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I am having a certificate, trying to set the certificate to "javax.net.ssl.keyStore".

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "certs/certfile.p12");
  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");

//( fully qualified path is something like this src/main/resources/certs/certfile.p12 )

These properties are working fine when i run in local, but in docker conatiner the issue is, no such file or directory at certs/certfile.p12.

I need to add that certfile.p12 to the javax.net.ssl.keyStore in JAR. 
Alternate solutions are also accepted.

Note: fully qualified path will won't work in JAR.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide the image you're using and what command are you using to start the container?

Comment: I am not starting the conatiner, i am trying to deploy in higher environments. I can provide the screenshot of the error.

Here is the log

java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/tls/certfile.p12 (No such file or directory)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_212]

Comment: uhm how does the `certs/certfile.p12` file arrive on docker? is there a folder that gets mounted or is it copied during the build process?

Comment: That folder is manually added during development, and its a part of the jar.

Answer (score 3):

It's good practice (to try) to keep configuration external to an image. Apart from the obvious flexibility this provides (one image with many possible configurations), this also provides some safety in that config (e.g. certs) are managed externally (and presumably securely).

You have 2 options:

- Mount the `certfile.p12` into a volume when you create|run the container:

```
docker run \
.... \
--volume=path/to/local/certfile.p12:/path/to/image/certfile.p12 \
...
```

- Not recommended (see preamble), you include the `certfile.p12` in your image. This wold require you to create a new image (requiring a Dockerfile):

```
FROM original-image
...
ADD /path/to/local/certfile.p12 /path/to/image/certfile.p12
...
```

Your configuration requires a `password` being set too. It would be a good practice to externalize this value from the image as well. One way to do this would be to use an environment variable that you must then get from withing your Java app. You may set the variable:

```
docker run \
...
---env=PASSWORD=password
...
```